# jQuery Show more/Show less toggle height in div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, addclass, removeclass

I have a div containing images that I want to be 440px high to start with, with a 'show more' button which makes it full height (2750px). When at full height, I want the show more button to read 'show less' and for the function to be reversed when I click it.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#photo_container').css('height','440px');
$('#photo_container').css('overflow','hidden');
$('.show_more').click(function(){
$('#photo_container').animate({'height':'2750px'},500);
$('.show_more').html('<h4>Show Less</h4>');
$('.show_more').addClass('show_less');
$('.show_more').removeClass('show_more');
});                        
$('.show_less').click(function(){
$('#photo_container').animate({'height':'440px'},500);
$('.show_less').html('<h4>Show More</h4>');
$('.show_less').addClass('show_more');
$('.show_less').removeClass('show_less');

});
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="photo_container">
PHOTOS HERE...
</div>
<div class="show_more"><h4>Show more</h4></div>
```

My code allows me to expand, but it won't work the opposite way (show less). Can anyone explain to me why this is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your events to these instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-less', function() {
$(document).on('click', '.show-more', function() {
```

Because you're changing the class, you need to bind to the class and not to the element.